# Is it right for us to help more non-Christians people as compare to Christians? jesus sacrifice for us then more eligible christians or some ane else?

Tags: bible

i need the answers .. first tell me christians belong to Jesus or some one else.. if jesus sacrifice for us .. then first preference go the christians not the others religions right.. Do you know that jesus more love isreal not the others people  .. so tell me we have to prefer christianity or the buddist, muslims etc..

Comment: I think your question title is wrong. Do you mean "Is it right to help non-Christians more than Christians?"

Comment: yes .. you are absolutely right..

Comment: Please click the [edit] button and do the changes.

Comment: However, isn't "Is it right to..." essentially unanswerable? It's all a question of point of view. Presumably the people who do it think it's exactly the right thing to do.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your question, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: That said, this question falls outside the scope of this site.  General philosophical or sociological questions are off-topic unless clearly asking for a doctrinal answer.See: [On-topic and constructive examples](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/779/on-topic-and-constructive-examples). 
For suggestion on how this question could be salvaged, see [Tips for editing a question to make it suitable for re-opening](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/tips-for-editing-a-question-to-make-it-suitable-for-re-opening)

Comment: This appears to be a question about the United States government, which represents people of many different faiths.  Thus, this is a political question and not one that has to do with Christianity.

Comment: If this becomes on-topic, answerers may want to note [Galatians 6:10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=gal%206:10&version=ESV)

Answer (score 5):

You should help people despite them being Christian or non-Christian

**Mark 12:31 NIV**

> The second is this: 'Love your neighbor as yourself.' There is no
>   commandment greater than these.

What is important is that it does NOT say, "love your neighbor as yourself, if he believes like you do".  Also, I would suggest that it would be against Jesus' teachings to even consider helping someone or not based on their status of being a Christian, Jew, or neither.

---

There's another way to read the OP's question, which would be, "why isn't American (being a Christian nation) helping Christians in Pakistan?"  If that is the OP's intended question, then the question is political and off topic for Christianity.SE.  Christians in Pakistan (or any other country) shouldn't expect America to specifically help them due to their Christian status.  America is not a Christian nation and is not the leading voice for Christianity.  76% of people in America identify themselves as Christian.  Christians generally assert that America was founded on Christian principles and many would assume (but not say) that it is a Christian nation.  However, it's just as likely that America has influenced Christianity.  For example, toleration of other faiths is not a Christian principle - especially during the dark ages.  Does that appear to contradict the above bible quote?  Yes, yes it does.  Therefore there are differences between the mainstream Christian Church and some teachings from the bible for better or worse.  There are too many to list here and I will not engage in a comment tit for tat with anyone over this.

Comment: right sir.. but why Jesus give the preference the Isreali people Can you tell me plz.

Comment: Genesis 12:3 and Numbers 24:9 are usually considered to be speaking of the Israelites.  Christians believe that they will be bless for helping them.  I'm not sure what greater blessing there could be than eternal life... but apparently a little more helps.

Comment: With that said, please see Mark 12:31 above.  What you are suggesting is that we should preference people based on their religion (we should help you before our neighbors).  I strongly feel that would not be the moral of Jesus' teachings.  Furthermore, you are specifically requesting help from America / Americans which is distinct from requesting help from Christians.  Modus tollens and Modus ponens can be applied here.

Answer (score 3):

As far as whether it is right or wrong that cannot be answered since it is subjective.

As to why we do it that is easy to answer: We do it because Jesus told us to!

Mat 5:42 through 48  KJV

> 42  Give to him that asketh thee, and from him that would borrow of thee turn not thou away.
>
> 43  Ye have heard that it hath been said, Thou shalt love thy neighbour, and hate thine enemy.
>
> 44  But I say unto you, Love your enemies, bless them that curse you, do good to them that hate you, and pray for them which despitefully use you, and persecute you;
>
> 45  That ye may be the children of your Father which is in heaven: for he maketh his sun to rise on the evil and on the good, and sendeth rain on the just and on the unjust.
>
> 46  For if ye love them which love you, what reward have ye? do not even the publicans the same?
>
> 47  And if ye salute your brethren only, what do ye more than others? do not even the publicans so?
>
> 48  Be ye therefore perfect, even as your Father which is in heaven is perfect.

If we do no less than what we are able to do to be as Jesus was, then we are not worthy of being his disciples.

That goes along with his commands 'to do unto others as you would have them do unto you, and turn the other cheek'.

Comment: i need the answers .. first tell me christians belong to Jesus or some one else.. if jesus sacrifice for us .. then first preference go the christians not the others religions.. Do you know that jesus more love isreal not the others people right .. so tell me we have to prefer christianity or the buddist etc..

Comment: @ Wilson We on this site do not judge whether or not one Religion is better than another. We will tell you what we believe to be the truth, but only you can make the choice of which religion you wish to follow. We call that Free will and it is central to the Christian faith.

Comment: right sir .. but some of Questions i saw about the out side the christianity.. so i just want to know the thinking power of christians. but i dont know why they put my question on hold..

Comment: We do not engage in confrontational debate, and will not debate in commentaries.